# Request, software to draw publishing quality diagrams

Tags: schematics

I'm trying to find a new solution for nice publishing quality schematics (as opposed as prntscreen ltspice as I'm doing right now) I downloaded dia and toyed with it but it doesn't seem to have a large community around it, not that intuitive of an interface and not that many symbols. It looked promising however. So I'm looking for visio kind of software, open source ideally (eventhough I know I could ''acquire'' it) with nice GUI ( I can't imagine texing a circuit like for Circuitikz) and a lot of symbols. Basically as easy as ltspice to use but options to make it look nicer, export to pdf, resize symbols etc. Any recommandations? What do you people use?

Comment: Could you link to original question?

Answer (score 0):

[CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) exports schematic images into beautiful vector PDF, EPS, SVG formats -- as well as raster PNGs.  See [some samples here](https://www.circuitlab.com/blog/2012/06/08/publication-quality-schematics-pdf-png-eps/).

Comment: CircuitLab isn't free...